# using text box value in different actions in MVC 5

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have these input in Login view, and i want to use their values in different part of the code,
i use Request.Form[""] . but this work just for the action of this view(Login action).
if there is any way to use the value in many actions?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ConfirmRegistration", "Regestration"))

    {
<h4>userName: <input type = "text" name="USERNAME" class="form-control" id="USERNAME"  /></h4>
<h4>Password: <input type = "password" name="pasword" class="form-control" id="pasword" /></h4>
<input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn-primary" />

   }
```

Comment: Please add code in question not in image link

Comment: You can't save global variables, what you could do is use ViewBag or ViewData, but these only work on the next view you show. One solution would be using cookies, but I'm not sure how to use them

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `Session` in your C# code. Your controller action method will look something like this.

```
        public ActionResult Login(FormCollection form)
        {
            //first, your logic to log user in

            //if credentials match, then store them into the Session
            Session["username"] = form["USERNAME"].ToString();
            Session["password"] = form["pasword"].ToString();


        }

        //to access the data from some other action, write:
        public ActionResult anyAction()
        {
            string username = Session["username"].ToString();
            string password = Session["password"].ToString();

            //and then do whatever you wanna do with them
        }
```

They are even accessible at your view level. just use C# razors like `@Session["username"].toString()` and `@Session["password"].toString()` to get the values.

Comment: Apparently you must first do a database operation to check user's credentials match, and then insert them into the session. Advantage of using sessions is that you can determine your own ways of session timeouts and other manipulations and notify user accordingly.